# mac os12.4 python: error: Failed to locate 'python'

Tags: python, macos

this error comes when I type cd ./

```
python: error: Failed to locate 'python'. 
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

Comment: macos uses ```which``` using ```which python``` should tell you if it is installed

Answer (score 37):

if it's related to any tools that require `xcode-install` you want to use `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3`
which points to some `../Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions`

like:
`sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python`

Comment: This definitely seems to have done the trick! It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: it works for me on Xcode 14.0.1! And Xcode complaint "env: python: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to install Xcode app, you should try this.

This worked for me

[Original answer in apple developers forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704099?answerId=719739022#719739022)

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python
```

This command creates the required python binary for xcode-select.

Comment: So far, that's the only thing that worked for me on macOS Ventura; the other solutions yielded `Operation not permitted` while this one simply worked, I can now invoke `python` without getting the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, when i use `sudo ln -s $(which python3)  /usr/local/bin/python`,  the problem still exists.

I tried to find the location of xcode-select and add it again.

The problem is resloved.

```bash
sudo ln -s $(which python3) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

[https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aenn5.png)

mac dosen't install python by default now.
so I need to install python and link to it.

```
sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python
```

works well in my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).